# Como funciona node cuando hago un setInterval dentro de otro setInterval?

Tags: nodejs, setinterval

Buenas tardes estoy empezando a usar nodejs y se me ocurrio probar un setInterval dentro de otro setInterval y el resultado que esperaba fue distinto al que ocurrió, les dejo lo que hice y el resultado.

```
    console.log('Hola mundo');

    setInterval(function(){
        console.log('Estoy aca.');
        setInterval(function(){
            var a =90;
            console.log(a);
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);

    console.log('segunda etapa.')
```

resultado:

```
    Hola mundo
    segunda etapa.
    Estoy aca.
    90
    Estoy aca.
    90
    90
    Estoy aca.
    90
    90
    90
    Estoy aca.
```

mi pregunta es..., el setInterval toma los 1000ms del primer setInterval y luego los otros 1000ms los divide dentro del otro setInterval o como sería?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente estas creando un hilo nuevo en cada intervalo

Así que tendrás un interval extra por segundo, lo que incrementara el uso de memoria exponencialmente (a los 60 segundos tendrás 61 intervalos dando vuelta)

Si lo que quieres es llamar a uno y cerrar el anterior, puedes hacer algo como esto:

```js
var primerInterval = setInterval(hacerAlgo,1000)
var calls = 0;
function hacerAlgo(){
    console.log('Estoy aca.');
    setInterval(function(){
        calls++;
        console.log(calls);
    }, 1000);
    // cerramos el primer interval
    clearInterval(primerInterval);        
};
```

Comment: hola, haa entonces se me iba a caer si lo dejaba mucho tiempo, bien lo entendí.
muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La traza es sencilla, primero se muestra el mensaje "Hola mundo", luego se crea el intervalo de 1000ms y por último se emite el mensaje "segunda etapa".

Pasados los 1000ms, se dispara el setInterval, muestra "Estoy aca." y crea un nuevo intervalo de 1000ms.

Pasados otros 1000ms se dispara el primer intervalo y vuelve a mostrar "Estoy aca.". También se dispara el segundo intervalo, el que está anidado, mostrando "90" y creando un tercer intervalo de 1000ms.

*** NOTA: En este momento la salida deberá mostrar

Hola mundo
Segunda etapa
Estoy aca.
Estoy aca.
90

En tu ejemplo sólo muestras un "Estoy aca.". Es posible que esto sea porque la consola de tu navegador los haya agrupado y en realidad te lo esté mostrando así

Hola mundo
Segunda etapa
(2) Estoy aca.
90

*** Fin de la nota.

Pasados otros 1000ms se repite el último paso y se crea un cuarto intervalo de 1000ms, mostrándose

Hola mundo
Segunda etapa
Estoy aca.
Estoy aca.
90 
Estoy aca.
90
90

y así sucesivamente.

A nivel didáctico esto está bien, pero en la práctica es una locura porque te creará intervalos anidados indefinidamente (hasta que el navegador acabe fallando)

Comment: gracias por contestar.
ahí va, llegaría un momento en el que perdería lo que está haciendo el programa.
El (2) no me lo mostró pero capaz que es porque lo corria en visual  studio y eso no lo muestra.